# Mongo Rest interface

Tags: mongodb, rest

Are sort queries supported through the Mongo Rest interface?

```
http://localhost:28017/udc/ProvisionStateEntity/
```

The above call will get the oldest records.

How to get the latest records?

Comment: If you're asking about the Simple Rest interface (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-interface), then no it does not. That endpoint is intended for basic admin only.

Comment: which REST interface are you using?